# How to save and restore navigation state in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to navigate to another screen, but i want to save current state, and then restore it. I tried to do as described in the [bottom navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav):

```
navController.navigate(Screen.CameraScreen.route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
            saveState = true
        }
    restoreState = true
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
navController.navigate(Screen.CameraScreen.route) {
        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
            popUpTo(route) {
                saveState = true
            }
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = true
    }
```

Comment: no, not saving text in textfields. It also goes back to the first screen.

Comment: This saves state in an app using tab-bar and switching between tabs. Just remember to use `rememberSaveable` like `val productCount =rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }` Thank you. :-)

Answer (score -1):

#### Update 1 :

You may also need to call saveState() function on navController

#### You can use this for handle clicks on navItem:

```kotlin
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    
...
onClick = {
    if (navItem.screen_route != currentDestination?.route) {
        Log.d("Navigation", "Try to navigate")

        navController.navigate(navItem.screen_route) {
            // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
            // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
            // on the back stack as users select items
            // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when

            if (currentDestination != null) {
                Log.d("Navigation", "Pop up current destination")
                popUpTo(currentDestination.id) {
                    saveState = true
                    inclusive = true
                }
            } else {
                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                    saveState = true
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }

            // reselecting the same item
            launchSingleTop = true
            // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
            restoreState = true
        }
    }
}
...
```

#### and you should be use [rememberSaveable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary#rememberSaveable(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.Saver,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0)) for saveable values

---

> [Restoring state in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state)
>
> > Use rememberSaveable to restore your UI state after an activity or process is recreated. rememberSaveable retains state across recompositions. In addition, rememberSaveable also retains state across activity and process recreation.

> [Ways to store state](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#ways-to-store)
>
> > All data types that are added to the Bundle are saved automatically. If you want to save something that cannot be added to the Bundle, there are several options.

> [Parcelize](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#parcelize)
>
> > The simplest solution is to add the [@Parcelize](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md) annotation to the object. The object becomes parcelable, and can be bundled. For example, this code makes a parcelable City data type and saves it to the state.

---

Like this :

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class City(val name: String, val country: String) : Parcelable

@Composable
fun CityScreen() {
    var selectedCity = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(City("Madrid", "Spain"))
    }
}
```

---

Also, you can use [MapSaver](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#mapsaver) like this :

```kotlin
data class City(val name: String, val country: String)

val CitySaver = run {
    val nameKey = "Name"
    val countryKey = "Country"
    mapSaver(
        save = { mapOf(nameKey to it.name, countryKey to it.country) },
        restore = { City(it[nameKey] as String, it[countryKey] as String) }
    )
}

@Composable
fun CityScreen() {
    var selectedCity = rememberSaveable(stateSaver = CitySaver) {
        mutableStateOf(City("Madrid", "Spain"))
    }
}
```

---

And also, [ListSaver](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#listsaver) :

```kotlin
data class City(val name: String, val country: String)

val CitySaver = listSaver<City, Any>(
    save = { listOf(it.name, it.country) },
    restore = { City(it[0] as String, it[1] as String) }
)

@Composable
fun CityScreen() {
    var selectedCity = rememberSaveable(stateSaver = CitySaver) {
        mutableStateOf(City("Madrid", "Spain"))
    }
}
```

#### *Probably, with the information I provided, you don't need to refer to the reference sources. Just try coding !*

Comment: This does not even begin to answer the question asked.

Comment: @colintheshots ,
Check my new edit .
I hope it can solves the problem